# React proxy not changing port

Tags: reactjs, spring, proxy, create-react-app

I create new react app using create-react-app and add `"proxy": "http://localhost:8080",`
`"allowedHosts": "*",` to `package.json` and i also tried using `setupProxy.js`:

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require("http-proxy-middleware");

module.exports = function (app) {
    app.use(
      "/api",
      createProxyMiddleware({
        target: "http://localhost:8080",
        changeOrigin: true,
      })
    );
};
```

and in `App.js` i make a link to go to `/api/demo/hello`:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <a href="/api/demo/hello">hello</a>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

when press that link, it return `Whitelabel Error Page` and in console `GET http://localhost:3000/api/demo/hello 404 (Not Found)` (react running on port 3000).

My java spring backend:

```
@RestController // This means that this class is a Controller
@RequestMapping(path="/demo") // This means URL's start with /demo (after Application path)
public class MainController {
@GetMapping("/hello")
public String hello(@RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "World") String name) {
    return String.format("Hello %s!", name);
}
```

If i go to `http://localhost:8080/demo/hello` manually it work fine.

Delete `package-lock.json` and `node-module` and run `npm install` not fix it.